# File.listFile() does not work properly

Tags: java, android, android-file

I am creating directory picker for my app, and I have faced the following issue: method File.listFile() does not list 120GB+ SD cards (I mean there is no mounted folder anywhere). It works great with smaller cards, but not with those. Library starts from Environment.getExternalStorage() or root path and then can go up and down at the tree. Maybe there are some extra volumes I forget about? This issue was found on Samsung, btw.

Comment: And what is the Filesystem of this card exFAT, or FAT32 ? there are articles about issues with exFAT...

Comment: @n00dl3 I have no idea. It is a bug report. Can you provide any solution for any of mentioned, please?

Comment: No idea about how to solve, but there is [the article I found](http://www.androidauthority.com/high-capacity-microsd-cards-android-gary-explains-690710/) that says Android sdcard compatibility is not quite simple... It highly depends on the phone... But 128GB is an SDXC card, and it seems it may fail on cheap or old devices.

Comment: Wich android version? does your device support 120GB+ SD cards ? do you have other apps that can read the big sd card? I assume that your app has read-file-permissions

Comment: @k3b it is android 6. Device - Samsung galaxy s7 edge. There is an another app from googleplay, which recognizes those card (unfortunately it is not mine).